# iMac 10.6.8 pointing fail with Bluetooth enabled

Tags: trackpad

10.6 Aluminum iMac w/wireless keyboard and trackpad.

Working fine long-term, no recent change to the h/w or system software.

All of a sudden pointing started operating as if permanently in mouse-down state.  In Finder, this means that the mouse would move around the last-selected object.  It is impossible to put the object down and so impossible to operate the Mac.  Restart doesn't help.

I turned off the wireless devices, replaced the wireless keyboard and trackpad with old, wired keyboard and mouse, and restarted. Normal operation was restored.  Tried putting back the the keyboard, but pointing was disabled the instant I re-enabled Bluetooth.  Now stuck permanently as if in mouse-up state, so impossible to operate.  Fail.

Temporarily OK with wired keyboard and mouse.  Ideas how to return the system to wireless keyboard and trackpad operation?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

First, the underlying cause MAY have been an unusual circumstance: a smartphone (Galaxy Android) was placed next to the iMac, turned on and with Bluetooth enabled, and left for hours to charge.  Could this proximity have resulted in the Mac getting some strange Bluetooth input?

Fix:  Using the temporarily-installed mouse and keyboard, I removed the existing Bluetooth keyboard and trackpad entries. (I just removed every Bluetooth device.)  Then I used the standard procedure to re-pair the wireless keyboard and trackpad.

After removing all Bluetooth devices, I could not get the Mac to detect any Bluetooth devices until I restarted the Mac, at which point device detection and pairing worked flawlessly.

My best --and admittedly ignorant, sketchy-- theory:   Some mal-formed event got stuck in the Bluetooth input stream, causing the trackpad up and/or down states to be hyper-sticky.  That event couldn't be cleared without removing the originating device and re-pairing.

HTH